# Why does HERE geocoder API come return different results than HERE maps search?

Tags: here-api

Given a sample address, I get back an inaccurate result from the HERE Geocoder API.  However, if I enter that same address string into the HERE maps website (https://maps.here.com/), it appears to place the address correctly.

Is the HERE maps website not using the same back end location services?

My sample string: `800 W Miner St, West Chester, PA 19382`

If you go to the maps site and search for that string it comes back somewhat near where Google places it.  But the Geocoder API comes back with a generic "center of the city sort of near the street" response below.

I would chalk it up to a bad input and move on, but it's strange the maps website comes back with a different result than the API - I would assume they would be doing similar work.

The JSON response from the API explorer https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-no-attributes

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2016-01-22T19:04:38.969+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "PerformedSearch": {
          "SearchText": "800 W Miner St, West Chester, PA 19382",
          "MetaInfo": {
            "internalUse": false,
            "Generation": 9
          },
          "RepresentationOptions": {
            "Language": [],
            "MaxResults": 10,
            "StrictLanguageMode": false,
            "SearchResponseAttributes": [
              "label",
              "didYouMeanSuggestion",
              "matchQuality",
              "matchType",
              "performedSearch"
            ],
            "PlaceAttributes": [
              "categories",
              "location",
              "supplier",
              "contact",
              "additionalData",
              "alternativeNames"
            ],
            "LocationAttributes": [
              "address",
              "mapView",
              "additionalData",
              "shape"
            ],
            "AddressAttributes": [
              "country",
              "state",
              "county",
              "city",
              "district",
              "subdistrict",
              "street",
              "houseNumber",
              "postalCode",
              "suite",
              "floor",
              "streetDetails",
              "localizedNames",
              "additionalData",
              "alternativeAttributes",
              "building"
            ]
          }
        },
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 0.82,
            "MatchLevel": "street",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "State": 1,
              "City": 1,
              "Street": [
                0.95
              ],
              "PostalCode": 1
            },
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_gJx8pmEXcMN1MhlAfdQfjD",
              "LocationType": "address",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 39.96225,
                "Longitude": -75.5967
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 39.96225,
                  "Longitude": -75.5967
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 39.96337,
                  "Longitude": -75.60351
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 39.95883,
                  "Longitude": -75.59413
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "E Miner St, West Chester, PA 19382, United States",
                "Country": "USA",
                "State": "PA",
                "County": "Chester",
                "City": "West Chester",
                "Street": "E Miner St",
                "PostalCode": "19382",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "United States",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Pennsylvania",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Chester",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "N",
                    "key": "PostalCodeType"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there an API for however the maps site is finding locations?  Or any way to reconcile these two different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here.com is a customized application, i believe for providing suggestions here.com uses Places API first rather than Geocoder

http://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/suggest?q=800+W+Miner+St%2C+West+Chester%2C+PA+19382&X-Map-Viewport=13.3704%2C52.5122%2C13.4194%2C52.5262&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Comment: I ended up poking through the network calls in Chrome's developer tools and saw the same thing.  It appears that the web frontend uses their Places API, sometimes makes a similar call to the geocoder API, but mostly passes Places results back and forth. It's still interesting that whatever backend process is finding the address location under the Places API is doing something different than the Geocoder API.  Thanks for the link to the API browser, too...I didn't know that existed.

Comment: I have a similar problem - except I see the different results between using a) the geocoder REST api (6.2 and gen=9), and b) the geocoder javascript library (v3/3.0).

The REST 6.2 call returns matchLevel=city, but the javascript v3/3.0 call returns matchLevel=houseNumber.

Does anyone know the reason?  Should they return the same?  Or does the javascript library also do something different like using Places?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: One additional hint - we haven't seemed to have this problem for US addresses, but seem to see it frequently for CANADA addresses.  Don't know why.