# Here Geocoder inaccuracies when requesting co-ordinates for a postcode

Tags: here-api

When sending city, postcode, country code in a structured query to the API, the results seem to be way off what is actually required.

**Example #1 - City, Postcode, Country (removed API Key)**

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=XXXXX&qq=city=OXFORD;postalCode=OX2+0ES;country=GBR
```

This API call returns a result for postalCode `OX1 3` which is not what I am looking for.

```
{
            "title": "Oxford, England",
            "id": "here:cm:namedplace:20338152",
            "resultType": "locality",
            "localityType": "city",
            "address": {
                "label": "Oxford, England",
                "countryCode": "GBR",
                "countryName": "England",
                "countyCode": "OXF",
                "county": "Oxfordshire",
                "city": "Oxford",
                "postalCode": "OX1 3"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 51.75629,
                "lng": -1.25951
            },
```

**Example #2 - Postcode, Country (removed API Key)**

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=XXXXX&qq=postalCode=OX2+0ES;country=GBR
```

This call returns the postcode `OX2 0`, which is closer to what I searched for, but still not accurate enough?

```
        {
            "title": "OX2 0, Oxford, England",
            "id": "here:cm:namedplace:22218302",
            "resultType": "locality",
            "localityType": "postalCode",
            "address": {
                "label": "OX2 0, Oxford, England",
                "countryCode": "GBR",
                "countryName": "England",
                "countyCode": "OXF",
                "county": "Oxfordshire",
                "city": "Oxford",
                "postalCode": "OX2 0"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 51.76224,
                "lng": -1.27976
            },
```

In some cases I have found while testing, is that the difference between the co-ordindates for the returned partial postcode and the full postcode is >= 8 miles out.

The question is, why when you attempt to be more accurate (including city) the response is inaccurate?

Also, if you are sending a full UK postcode to the Geocoder, why does it only resolve to part of the postcode? Surely if you send a full postcode, it should match?

Or, perhaps I need to use a different API. I did [see another question with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954138/why-does-here-geocoder-api-come-return-different-results-than-here-maps-search) that mentions Places API. Should this be used instead?

Comment: Could you please try 4 digits of the postalCode like an example below:
```https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=city=OXFORD;postalCode=OX2 0;country=GBR```
In GBR, we support 4 digits zip code, that's why when you use OX2+0ES it seems the zipcode was not taken by the services.